# Workflows in SharePoint 2013 online

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online

Hello a question about workflows in sharepoint 2013 online

I have a collumn named Category with choices:
IT
Phone
Other

when the user creates a new item in the list, if he choose in the category, IT. The IT department gets an email that an order has been.

If the user choose "phone", The Phone department gets an email that an order has been.

Can this be acchieved by workflows in sharepoint, or do i need to use sharepoint designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No OOB workflow will do that for you. You have to create a SharePoint Designer workflow that will do the following:

1. Read the Department property
2. Add IF conditions to check the value of the Departments property
3. Inside each IF block, send the e-email to the correct users.

Hope this helps.